# Spring JPA generates SELECT query for new associated entities of existing owning entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an owning entity class with some associated entities, e.g.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Child> children;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    private UUID parentId;
    ...
}
```

I am using Spring Boot Starter Data JPA. I traced the code to the `SimpleJpaRepository` class, I noticed that on calling `save(parent)`, it checks if `isNew()` returns true, Spring will call `persist()`; otherwise it calls `merge()`. This makes total sense, as `persist()` will generate only an INSERT, while `merge()` will generate a SELECT (if it hasn't done before) and then followed by an INSERT if the SELECT returns nothing; otherwise an UPDATE.

The above works well when saving a new `Parent` with new `Child`, only INSERTs are generated without any SELECT.

However, my problem is, when creating some new `Child` and adding them to an **existing** `Parent`, then on saving the parent, somehow I noticed Spring JPA is still generating an extra SELECT for each of these new `Child` entities before the INSERTs, which I found unnecessary.

Is there a way to avoid these SELECT queries?

---

Further investigation I found that if I leave the `id` of the `Child` null (i.e. let it auto generates a new id), then only INSERT is generated. However, if I manually assign an id to a `Child`, then a SELECT will be generated before an INSERT. Is there a way I can assign id to `Child` while avoiding the extra SELECT?

Comment: Provide the full mapping for `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne` as well as the `@Id` mappings. AFAIK it can depend on the mapping if hibernate needs to perform a select or not

Comment: @XtremeBaumer updated to include more info.

Comment: Shouldn't `private UUID parentId;` be `private Parent parentId;`? What is the mapping from child to parent?

Comment: You should also read this: [How to merge entity collections with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/merge-entity-collections-jpa-hibernate/)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer is a unidirection relationship, the child does not need to know about its parent

Comment: [Check this](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-unidirectional-one-to-many-association-without-junction-table/). I still think that your mapping wouldn't work like this. You would need a `@JoinColumn` on `List<Child> children;` and the `mappedBy` attribute is not necessary

Comment: If you assign an ID before inserting the entity is in a `detached` state and hibernate thinks the entity already exists in the database, thus performs a select to check if that is actually the case and to get a managed instance. As the select does not return anything, it runs an insert instead of an update. You would have to manually persist each child as to not trigger a select

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of your code  i think because of OnetoMany mapping and you did't provide cascade type then it not  happen
select query running two times
provide more information
full code of Entity classes
properties file

Comment: More information added

Comment: This looks more like a comment!